# Drawing texts above each polygon's line Python

Tags: python, math

I have a painter application that draws shapes (polygon shapes), and I want to display a text in the middle and on top of each line of that polygon.

**Note:** there are special cases where the line has 90* degrees the text will be on the right side

**So my question is:** how should I calculate the correct offset from the middle point of the line so the text will appear as I described (on top of the line and in the middle)

like the page showing (red points refer to the point in the mid of the line).
[image: polygon shape with text in the middle and above each line]

what I've achieved so far is:

1. calculate the midpoint of each line (the red points in the picture).
2. calculate the angle of the line with the x-axis and determine the offset value (I don't see is an optimal solution as well the results are not good)
   **Note:** I needed to set an offset because if I made the text exactly on the middle line point that causes the text and the line to overlap so I need to shift the text left/right in order to accomplish my goal (make the text always on top of the line).

**Here is a very newbie code :)**

```
    def get_middle_line_point(line):
      x1, x2 = line[0][0], line[1][0]
      y1, y2 = line[0][1], line[1][1]
      m_point = Point((x1 + x2) / 2 - 20, (y1 + y2) / 2, 0)
      return m_point


    def get_angle(line):
      dx = line[1].x() - line[0].x()
      dy = line[1].y() - line[0].y()
      theta = math.atan2(dy, dx)
      angle = math.degrees(theta)  # angle is in (-180, 180]
      offset, axis = 0, None
      if angle < 0:
          angle = 360 + angle

      if angle == 90 or angle == 270:
          offset, axis = -35, 'x'

      if 0 < angle < 40:
          offset, axis = -35, 'y'

      if 40 < angle < 90:
          offset, axis = 35, 'x'

      if 90 < angle < 180:
          offset, axis = -45, 'x'

      if 180 < angle < 270:
          offset, axis = 35, 'x'

      if 270 < angle < 320:
          offset, axis = -45, 'x'

      if 320 < angle < 360:
          offset, axis = -35, 'y'
      return offset, axis

m_point = get_middle_line_point(line) # the line has two points
offset, axis = get_angle(line)
if axis == 'x':
     m_point[0] += offset
else:
     m_point[1] += offset
draw_text(m_point, "text") # here we have the centre point of the target line and we set up 
the offset so the text won't overlap with the line
```

> Please if anything isn't clear let me know.

Answer (score 0):

What is `Point`? You haven't show the definition of it, so I can't run it.

But from this:

```py
def get_middle_line_point(line):
      x1, x2 = line[0][0], line[1][0]
      y1, y2 = line[0][1], line[1][1]
      m_point = Point((x1 + x2) / 2 - 20, (y1 + y2) / 2, 0)
      return m_point
```

From the way the variables are assigned, it is evident line is a list of two lists, each list containing two numbers, the first being x and the second being y.

You can assign x1, y1, x2, y2 in one line:

```py
(x1, y1), (x2, y2) = line
```

Again, I don't know what Point is, but presumably it should take x value and y value as argument.

Then if my math is correct, the middle point between two points should be:

```
(x1 + (x2 - x1) / 2, y1 + (y2 - y1) / 2)
```

That is, assuming x1 < x2 and y1 < y2.

You did this wrong, it is elementary mathematics...

Then if x1 > x2 or y1 > y2, just swap the variables...

Fixed function:

```py
def middle_point(line):
    (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = line
    if x1 > x2:
        x1, x2 = x2, x1
    if y1 > y2:
        y1, y2 = y2, y1
    return (x1 + (x2 - x1) / 2, y1 + (y2 - y1) / 2)
```

You have a bunch of if statements with very similar conditions, only with different values, and the output is also similar, you should check these values using a for loop and do early returns:

Fixed code:

```py
def get_angle(line):
      (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = line
      dx, dy = x2 - x1, y2 - y1
      theta = math.atan2(dy, dx)
      angle = math.degrees(theta)
      if angle < 0:
          angle = 360 + angle

      if angle in (90, 270):
          return -35, 'x'

      conditions = [
          (0, 40, -35, 'y'),
          (40, 90, 35, 'x'),
          (90, 180, -45, 'x'),
          (180, 270, 35, 'x'),
          (270, 320, -45, 'x'),
          (320, 360, -35, 'y')
      ]
      for a, b, c, d in conditions:
          if a < angle < b:
              return c, d
```

Full script:

```py
import math

def middle_point(line):
    (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = line
    if x1 > x2:
        x1, x2 = x2, x1
    if y1 > y2:
        y1, y2 = y2, y1
    return (x1 + (x2 - x1) / 2, y1 + (y2 - y1) / 2)


def get_angle(line):
      (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = line
      dx, dy = x2 - x1, y2 - y1
      theta = math.atan2(dy, dx)
      angle = math.degrees(theta)
      if angle < 0:
          angle = 360 + angle

      if angle in (90, 270):
          return -35, 'x'

      conditions = [
          (0, 40, -35, 'y'),
          (40, 90, 35, 'x'),
          (90, 180, -45, 'x'),
          (180, 270, 35, 'x'),
          (270, 320, -45, 'x'),
          (320, 360, -35, 'y')
      ]
      for a, b, c, d in conditions:
          if a < angle < b:
              return c, d
```

You have deviated from 4 spaces indentation...